# Responsive thumbnail grid resize on width

Tags: html, css, grid, width, thumbnails

It's must be quite easy to make a responsive thumbnail grid that resizes automatically when the width changes. But i have seen multiple ways how thumbnails grids are made some using ordered list structure:

```
<ol>
<li><img scr=""/></li>
<li><img scr=""/></li>
</ol>
```

Others just use a div and img structure so what is the best way to make a thumbnail grid?

In my example i have the content centered in the browser with a max-width of 750px and i want to place 5 square thumbnails that fill 100% of that space and automatically adjust there size when the width change. Also i want to play with the space between them adding space or remove all space and later on decide on that, but keep the 100% width of the content area and add space to top and bottom between the content text.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd9taz51/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t matter whether you use DIVs or an unordered or even ordered list. I tend to choose an unordered list for such a case as it feels semantically right for me. But the layout magic happens in your stylesheets.

A reason why I use lists is that it often comes in handy that you get a hierarchy of

- list

  - item

    - content

So you can use the list the container the list items’ sizes relate to (in your case 20%) while each list items’ content can be laid out in relation to its list item parent. You can just float the list items within the list (so don’t forget to clear float via :after pseudo element) or set display to inline-block (then you have to take out any white spaces between the LI tags within the list to prevent any gaps).

Tip: As relative vertical padding is always calculated in relation to the parent element’s *width* (not *height*!), it allows you to give every list item a fixed width/height ratio. As you want your thumbnails to be squares, you can set the list items padding-bottom to the same value as `width: 20%`. That’s especially useful if you don’t work with image elements but with background images. The downside is that any item content has to be positioned *absolute* within the item.

I’ve changed your fiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmdj2yq/6/

As long as the spacing between the list items is meant to be relative to the list container as well, it is just a bit of math. Like e.g. 5% in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmdj2yq/8/). 5 items have 4 gutter of 5% between them. So set `margin: 0 5% 5% 0` and `width: 16%` (=(100% - 5% * 4 gutters) / 5 items). Each list item’s :nth-child(5n) has to have its margin-right to be set to 0 to make it work.

As soon as you want to have fixed gutters it is getting more tricky. I usually do something like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmdj2yq/10/) and may require addition markup (I added link tags). The horizontal spacing is defined via the list items’ padding (items have `box-sizing: border-box;`), vertical spacing via margins. The list container has a negative margin on both sides. Check the styles.

Comment: Thanks Oliver! But how about giving the thumbnails space between them but still keep the 100% width on the left and right. Is that possible this way?

Comment: It’s easy and just a bit of math as long as your spacing is meant to be relative like the thumb sizes. Like e.g. 5% in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmdj2yq/8/).

Comment: You are welcome. I just updated the post and also added a fiddle that combines fluid item widths with fixed gutters.

Comment: Very useful example with fixed gutters.